# How to rewrite randomly generated nginx path by taking the first segment?

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have a prestashop instance that generates a random URL for admin access. The only rule is that the path starts with "admin".

The following rule works just fine, but its hardcoded by hand:

```
location /admin6908ewwh6/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/.*$ /admin6908ewwh6/index.php last;
    }
}
```

I tried to rewrite it into this:

```
location ^(/admin.*?)(\w+)/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/.*$ $1/index.php last;
    }
}
```

But this is not working, and I don't know why since according to this regex matcher ( https://www.regextester.com/102896 ) when I put a `^(/admin.*?)(\w+)` regex against a test string `/admin6908ewwh6/index.php/sell/catalog/products/new?_token=_JC1fQPwgvwnhZTWyeGVTy4nET350GC4Aro888TuzDA&` it just grabs what I need to take.

Can somebody explain me why these two location blocks are not equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$1`. Numeric captures are assigned by the last regular expression to be evaluated, which in this case is the `rewrite` statement (despite there being no parentheses in the regular expression).

One solution is to make the capture in the `rewrite` statement, for example:

```
location /admin {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(/admin[^/]+)/ $1/index.php last;
    }
}
```

---

Or without the `if` block:

```
location /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @admin;
}
location @admin {
    rewrite ^(/admin[^/]+)/ $1/index.php last;
}
```

---

Or without the `rewrite` statement:

```
location ~ ^(/admin[^/]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $1/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

*Ensure that this last location block is below the block that processes `.php` URIs.*